# add two fields and insert into third in domain class in grails

Tags: grails

I am working on a grails project in which i have a domain class having 3 fields. my requirement is to input only 2 fields and 3rd field get populated with the sum of both the fields. can anyone send me the code. thnks

Answer (score 3):

See [Derived properties](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties)

Example from above link

```
class Product {
    Float price
    Float taxRate
    Float tax
    static mapping = {
       tax formula: 'PRICE * TAX_RATE'
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's two complete ways of doing it, depending on your needs.

If you don't need to store the third field, meaning it's only used for display, you can do this:

```
class MyDomain {
    int field1
    int field2

    static transients = ['field3']

    getField3() {
        field1 + field2
    }
}
```

This will allow you to access the sum as `myDomain.field3`.

If you need to store it, say because it's heavily used in calculations, you can use events to automatically calculate and store the sum, like so:

```
class MyDomain {
    int field1
    int field2
    int field3

    def beforeInsert() {
        field3 = field1 + field2
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        field3 = field1 + field2
    }
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that the third field is populated no matter *where* it's created or updated.

Two Notes:

1. If you only want to sum `field3` when it's created, and not on updates, then remove `beforeUpdate`.
2. If you are doing more complex calculations than that simple sum, throw them in another method (like `updateField3`), and call that instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: I think This method works fine for transient properties, but if querying, criteria, and persistence is required, formula would still be a better choice.

Comment: I agree completely — that's why I gave you a +1! I had just finished writing mine when you posted, so I just posted mine for completeness.